# Custom signalling with Celery tasks

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

We're using Celery's Tasks for handling some messages that define what work needs to be done. Since these Task objects are spawned by Celery and not manually, there's a limitation on messaging that is imposed by Celery, where the signals sent can only be those defined on the app.

Currently, the plan is to have an AMQP consumer thread running within the Task process that Celery will create and that will be responsible for setting a flag/storing a value/whatever every time a specially crafted message is sent a specific *signals* queue.

Is there a specific feature of Celery that enables sending such signals without hacking in the extraneous and independent consumer? No Django on our environment.

Comment: I think Celery is designed for self-contained tasks. When I need to share state between tasks, I use a key-value store like redis (in fact I end up using a redis backend instead of AMQP - less one daemon to deploy).